No transform from [X] to [map] for multi robot simulation
No Transform Error in RViz Robot Model with Fetch Freight Robot Setup
I am encountering a "No Transform" error in RViz for the Robot Model (screenshot attached below). My setup involves launching two Fetch Freight robots in Gazebo and RViz, but for debugging, I simplified the setup to load only one Freight robot using namespace groups. My TF tree shows the hierarchy map -> odom -> base_link (TF tree diagram attached). I included a dummy link since my first link has inertia.
Questions:

How can I resolve the TF re-parenting and multiple authority
contention between /gazebo and /robot_state_publisher?
How do I solve No transform error in Rviz?
Are there specific configurations in the URDF/Xacro files or launch
files I should check to avoid transform conflicts?
Any tips to ensure smooth namespace isolation when launching
multiple robots in RViz and Gazebo?

Observations:

roswtf

ERROR TF re-parenting contention:


reparenting of [freight1/r_wheel_link] to [freight1/dummy] by [/gazebo]
reparenting of [freight1/l_wheel_link] to [freight1/dummy] by [/gazebo]
reparenting of [freight1/l_wheel_link] to [freight1/base_link] by [/freight1/robot_state_publisher]
reparenting of [freight1/r_wheel_link] to [freight1/base_link] by [/freight1/robot_state_publisher]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:

node [/gazebo] publishing transform [freight1/r_wheel_link] with parent [freight1/dummy] already published by node [/freight1/robot_state_publisher]
node [/gazebo] publishing transform [freight1/l_wheel_link] with parent [freight1/dummy] already published by node [/freight1/robot_state_publisher]
node [/freight1/robot_state_publisher] publishing transform [freight1/l_wheel_link] with parent [freight1/base_link] already published by node [/gazebo]
node [/freight1/robot_state_publisher] publishing transform [freight1/r_wheel_link] with parent [freight1/base_link] already published by node [/gazebo]


rosrun tf tf_monitor

Frames:
Frame: freight1/base_camera_link published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: freight1/base_camera_optical_frame published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: freight1/base_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.00093617 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: freight1/estop_link published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: freight1/l_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000402174 Max Delay: 0.002
Frame: freight1/laser_link published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: freight1/odom published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.499292 Max Delay: 0
Frame: freight1/r_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000402174 Max Delay: 0.002

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 135.153 Hz, Average Delay: -0.057149 Max Delay: 0.003
Node: unknown_publisher(static) 1e+08 Hz, Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0


sim.launch
    <launch>
  <arg name="robot" default="freight"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>

  <!-- Start Gazebo with a blank world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Launch map server
  <include file="$(find test4_multi_robot)/launch/server.launch" /> -->

  <!-- Load everything associated with Robot1 -->
  <include file="$(find test4_multi_robot)/launch/robot1.launch"  />
  
   
  <!-- Load Rviz -->
  <!-- <node type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(find test4_multi_robot)/src/rviz/rviz_config.rviz" /> -->

</launch>

robot1.launch
<launch>
    <arg name="robot1" value="freight1" />
    <arg name="robot1_x" value="1.0" />
    <arg name="robot1_y" value="1.0" />
    <arg name="robot1_z" value="0.0" />
    <arg name="robot1_yaw" value="0.0" />

    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find test4_multi_robot)/description/freight.urdf.xacro" />
    <node name="map" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find test4_multi_robot)/map/map.yaml" >
        <param name="Frame_id" value="/map" />
    </node>
    
    <group ns="freight1">
        
        <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-model $(arg robot1) -x $(arg robot1_x) -y $(arg robot1_y) -z $(arg robot1_z) -Y $(arg robot1_yaw) -urdf -param /robot_description " respawn="false" output="screen"/> 
        <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
            <!-- the below is important along with use_map topic in amcl1.launch to get fixed frame rviz -->
            <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg robot1)" />
        </node>

        <!-- include AMCL -->
        <include file="$(find test4_multi_robot)/launch/amcl1.launch">
            <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg robot1_x)"/>
            <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg robot1_y)"/>
            <arg name="initial_pose_z" value="$(arg robot1_z)"/>
            <arg name="initial_pose_yaw" value="$(arg robot1_yaw)"/>
        </include>

        <!-- inclde Move Base -->
        <!-- <include file="$(find test4_multi_robot)/launch/move_base1.launch"/> -->

    </group>


</launch>

amcl1.launch
<launch>
  <arg name="robot_name" default="freight1"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic"     default="/freight1/base_scan" />
  <arg name="map_topic"      default="/map" />
  <!-- send argments -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_x"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_z"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_yaw"/>


  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">
    <param name="use_map_topic"  value="true"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test4_multi_robot)/config/amcl1.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_z"            value="$(arg initial_pose_z)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_yaw"          value="$(arg initial_pose_yaw)"/>
    <param name="global_frame_id"           value="/map"/>
    <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    <remap from="initialpose"               to="/freight1/initialpose"/>
    <remap from="amcl_pose"                 to="/freight1/amcl_pose"/>
    <remap from="particlecloud"             to="/freight1/particlecloud"/>
    <remap from="map" to="$(arg map_topic)" />
    <!-- <remap from="static_map" to="/static_map"/> -->

  </node>

</launch>

freight.gazebo.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="freight" >
  

  <!-- Base is modeled as a big tub sitting on floor, with two wheels -->
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <kp>100000000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <mu1>0.1</mu1>
    <mu2>0.1</mu2>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <maxVel>10.0</maxVel>
    <minDepth>0.0005</minDepth>
  </gazebo>


  <gazebo reference="r_wheel_link">
    <kp>500000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <mu1>10</mu1>
    <mu2>10</mu2>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
    <minDepth>0.003</minDepth>
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
  </gazebo>


  <gazebo reference="l_wheel_link">
    <kp>500000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <mu1>10</mu1>
    <mu2>10</mu2>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
    <minDepth>0.003</minDepth>
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
  </gazebo>


  <gazebo reference="l_wheel_joint">
    <implicitSpringDamper>1</implicitSpringDamper>
  </gazebo>


  <gazebo reference="r_wheel_joint">
    <implicitSpringDamper>1</implicitSpringDamper>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- SICK TIM561 (25m Range) -->
  <gazebo reference="laser_link">
    <sensor type="ray" name="base_laser">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>15</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>662</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.91986</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.91986</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.05</min>
          <max>25.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <!-- Noise parameters based on spec for SICK TIM561 (10m version) -->
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.02</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_base_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>base_scan</topicName>
        <frameName>laser_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Color the estop -->
  <gazebo reference="estop_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Load the plugin -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="fetch_gazebo_plugin" filename="libfetch_gazebo_plugin.so"/>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Differential Drive Plugin for Robot -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_diff_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <leftJoint>l_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>r_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometrySource>world</odometrySource> <!-- Use "world" or "1", but not both -->

      <updateRate>30</updateRate>
      <wheelSeparation>0.160</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.066</wheelDiameter>
      <wheelAcceleration>1</wheelAcceleration>
      <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
      <rosDebugLevel>info</rosDebugLevel> <!-- Replace "na" with a valid level -->

      <publishWheelTF>true</publishWheelTF>
      <publishOdom>true</publishOdom>
      <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>

    </plugin>
  </gazebo>


</robot>

freight.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="freight" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:include filename="$(find test4_multi_robot)/description/freight.gazebo.xacro"/>
  <link name="dummy">
   </link>
  
  <link name="base_link">
    
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/base_link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.356 0.361 0.376 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/base_link_collision.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0036 0.0 0.0014" />
      <mass value="70.1294" />
      <inertia ixx="1.225" ixy="0.0099" ixz="0.0062" iyy="1.2853" iyz="-0.0034" izz="0.987" />
    </inertial>
  </link>


  <link name="r_wheel_link">
    
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/r_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.086 0.506 0.767 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/r_wheel_link_collision.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="4.3542" />
      <inertia ixx="0.0045" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.005" iyz="0" izz="0.0045" />
    </inertial>

  </link>


  <joint name="r_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="-6.123E-17 0 0" xyz="0.0012914 -0.18738 0.055325" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="r_wheel_link" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="8.85" velocity="34.8" />
  </joint>


  <link name="l_wheel_link">
    
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/l_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.086 0.506 0.767 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/l_wheel_link_collision.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="4.3542" />
      <inertia ixx="0.0045" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.005" iyz="0" izz="0.0045" />
    </inertial>
  </link>


  <joint name="l_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="-6.123E-17 0 0" xyz="0.0012914 0.18738 0.055325" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="l_wheel_link" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="8.85" velocity="34.8" />
  </joint>


  <link name="estop_link">
    
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/estop_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/estop_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.002434512737072 -0.00330608315239905 0.00665139196650039" />
      <mass value="0.00196130439134723" />
      <inertia ixx="3.02810026604417E-07" ixy="-1.5862023118056E-08" ixz="3.16561396557437E-08" iyy="2.93322917127605E-07" iyz="-4.28833522751273E-08" izz="2.28513272627183E-07" />
    </inertial>

  </link>


  <joint name="estop_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.12465 0.23892 0.31127" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="estop_link" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <joint name="dummy_joint" type="fixed">
     <parent link="dummy"/>
     <child link="base_link"/>
   </joint>

  <link name="laser_link">
    
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/laser_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://fetch_description/meshes/laser_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0306228970175641 0.0007091682908278 0.0551974119471302" />
      <mass value="0.00833634573995571" />
      <inertia ixx="1.01866461240801E-06" ixy="-5.88447626567756E-08" ixz="7.83857244757914E-08" iyy="5.10039589974707E-07" iyz="-7.12664289617235E-09" izz="1.28270671527309E-06" />
    </inertial>

  </link>


  <joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="3.14159265359 0 0" xyz="0.235 0 0.2878" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="laser_link" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>


  <link name="base_camera_link" />
  <joint name="base_camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 -0.17453292519943 0" xyz="0.2645 0 0.198" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="base_camera_link" />
  </joint>


  <link name="base_camera_optical_frame" />


  <joint name="base_camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267966 0 1.5707963267966" xyz="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_camera_link" />
    <child link="base_camera_optical_frame" />
  </joint>
</robot>



